# Random 502 errors from AWS Application load balancer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

We are receiving random 502 errors from our ALB, our backend does not get hit at all as there are no logs of the request.
Nothing from the ALB logs just the 502 error but nothing usable for debugging.

```
h2 2020-03-26T14:30:52.495547Z app/path/tomytarget 10.111.11.111:50103 100.00.00.00:8080:8080 0.001 18.799 -1 502 - 1213 208 "POST https://mydomain:443/user/auth HTTP/2.0" "Name/3 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.2.0" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-1:0000000000:targetgroup/path/tomytarget "Root=someId" "mydomain.com" "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:0000000000:certificate/certificatedId" 0 2020-03-26T14:30:33.694000Z "forward" "-" "-" "100.00.00.00:8080" "-"
```

We started noticing it after we enabled the health checks with a proper route in nodejs and express

```
app.get("/health-check", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

This is our ALB config and we are using VPC peering to another VPC

```
  ElasticLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref ELBSecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetA
        - !Ref PublicSubnetB
      Type: application

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Port: 8080
      Protocol: HTTP
      Targets:
        - Id: <some ip in the other VPC>
          AvailabilityZone: all
          Port: 8080
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: /health-check
      HealthCheckPort: 8080
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5

  Listener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ElasticLoadBalancer
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref CertificateArn
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
```

As I said we are using VPC peering and HTTPS with certificates coming from AWS certificate manager

[image]

#### EDIT:

if you are using nodejs one solution could be the following

```js
// AWS ALB keepAlive is set to 60 seconds, we need to increase the default KeepAlive timeout
// of our node server
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000; // Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 66000; // Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
```

Comment: Hey did you fix this problem? Im facing exactly the same :(
Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure we solved it entirely, but if you are using nodejs you could try to add this two lines of code: I will add them to my question otherwise in this comment the formatting would make it unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved like this in nodejs

```
// AWS ALB keepAlive is set to 60 seconds, we need to increase the default KeepAlive timeout
// of our node server
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000; // Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 66000; // Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
```